# How do i display the page of externaly selected row by index?

Tags: react-table

I'm simultaneously displaying some data in a react-table component and on a interactive map. I'm trying to implement a feature where items can be selected by clicking the table row or the object on the map.
[Here is what that looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hsba.png)

In my component's state there is a `selectedIndex` property that holds the array index of currently selected item.

I managed to handle the click events both on react-table row and on the interactive map object and set the appropriate value to the `selectedIndex` property.
I managed to highlight both the row that displays the selected item and the object that represents the selected item on the map.

```
getTrProps={(s: any, rowInfo: RowInfo) => {
  if (rowInfo == null) {
    return {};
  }
  return {
    onClick: (e: any, handleOriginal: any) => {
      this.handleSelectedIndexPress(rowInfo.index);
      if (handleOriginal) {
        handleOriginal();
      }
    },
    style: rowInfo.index === this.state.selectedIndex ?
      {background: '#00AFEC', color: 'white'} : {}
  }
}

<GlifyPointsLayer
  data={state.reportPoints}
  click={(e, point: [number, number, number]) => this.handleSelectedIndexPress(point[2])}
  color={{r: 1, g: 0, b: 1}}
  size={10}
/>
{state.selectedIndex != null &&
<Marker
  position={state.reportPoints[state.selectedIndex] as any}
  icon={markerIcon}
/>
```

The only problem is that when the user selects a item by clicking on it on the interactive map, sometimes, the item dose not get highlighted on the table since its not on the currently displayed page.

When that happens I would like to jump to the page where the selected item is.

I know that there is the `page` property on the `ReactTable` component with witch I can programmatically control the currently displayed page.
The problem is that when I handle the click event on the interactive map I only have access to the index of the selected element.

```
handleSelectedIndexPress = (index: number) => {
    // Here i need to figure out the page number that the row with index "index" is in.
    const selectedIndex = index !== this.state.selectedIndex ? index : null;
    this.setState({selectedIndex: selectedIndex});
};
```

How do I figure out what page number that index is in so that I can set the currently displayed page properly? Keep in mind that react-table rows can be sorted in many different ways so the index is not mathematically linked to the page number.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear, please could you remove all the extra things saying what you have done, and just give a short succinct question about what the problem is, and what you have tried to do to solve it. A small code example would be great too. Paragraphs are good too.

Comment: Edited the question.